# Four Colour Theorem: Can someone use four colours to completely colour this partition of the plane?

Tags: coloring

My friend gave me this partition and challenged me to color it using only four colors. I know that this is possible according to the four colors theorem but I failed miserably. Please HELP

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhJtr.jpg)

Comment: Start with a central region that forces neighbor regions to have different colors and move outward.  I can see the solution just by eye on this problem!  Not hard at all.  The enclosed regions (disk, hexagon) are trivial:  just must be different from encircling region.  The rest is easy.

Comment: First, find all the regions that are only adjacent to one other region. Color these last. This leaves you with less regions to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

there are many possibilities but one could be

[image]